# Unable to load CA private key when creating the intermediate pair

Tags: certificate, openssl, ssl-certificate, private-key, certificate-authority

Following the tutorial at [LINK](https://jamielinux.com/docs/openssl-certificate-authority/create-the-intermediate-pair.html) to create the root pair and intermediate pair.

Creating the root pair works fine, but when I try to create the intermediate pair using:

```
openssl ca -config openssl.cnf -extensions v3_intermediate_ca -days 3650 -notext -md sha256 -in intermediate/csr/intermediate.csr.pem -out intermediate/certs/intermediate.cert.pem
```

I get the following error:

```
Using Configuration from openssl.cnf
Can't open /root/ca/private/ca.key.pem for reading, No such file or directory
140382210524824:error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:crypto/bios/bss_file.c:398:fopen('/root/ca/private/ca.key.pem','r')
140382210524824:error:20074002:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file:crypto/bios/bss_file.c:76:
unable to load CA private key
```

The ca.key.pem file was encrypted using:

```
chmod 400 private/ca.key.pem
```

And I verified that I can see the CA's private key file using:

```
ls /root/ca/private/ca.key.pem
```

What is wrong?

Comment: How about also showing the contents of `openssl.cnf`?

Comment: FYI: `chmod 400` is not encrypting the ca.key.pem file.  It is simply setting it to read-only for the file owner.  Effectively protecting it from accidental deletion or modification.